# Need to hook to function of the Web API, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, web, hook, native-file-system-api-js

I'm trying to hook into a function that comes with the File System Access API.

For example when the web site used the File System Access API as shown in below.

```
// store a reference to our file handle
let fileHandle;

async function getFile() {
  // open file picker
  [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();

  if (fileHandle.type === 'file') {
    // run file code
  } else if (fileHandle.type === 'directory')
    // run directory code
  }

}
```

It is possible to hook Web APIs with JavaScript? I mean how can I stop process of the web site when it used this API?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "stop process of the web site". The API is asynchronous on purpose, so the call to open a file is not blocking.

Answer (score 2):

If by "hook" you mean intercept when the function was called, then you could override the built-in function like so:

```js
const originalShowOpenFilePicker = window.showOpenFilePicker;
window.showOpenFilePicker = (...args) => {
  console.log('Modified `showOpenFilePicker` called with these arguments:', args);
  // Block the page by calling `while (true) {}`,
  // but nor sure if this is what you mean. The
  // `return` statement below would be never reached
  // in this case. 
  return originalShowOpenFilePicker(...args);
};
```